# How do I load a string of numbers seperated by space to an array?

Tags: arrays, pascal

I need to create a program where in the first like of input I would put the number of numbers in the string separated by space, and in the second line I would enter them (for example 1 2 3 4 5 6). So I tried using Val, but it can't help me because there are spaces, also I can't use for because the numbers are in one line. Also numbers don't have to be one figure, they are from 1 to 10^9 .

Comment: post please your code so that we can help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the principle: Let s be your string. In a loop to the following

1. Remove leading spaces in s

   `while (length(s)>0) and (s[1]=' ') do delete(s,1,1);`
2. Find the first space in the remaining string

   `p := pos(' ',s);`
3. Copy the non-space part leading in a second string t and remove that part from s

   `t := copy(s,1,p-1);   delete(s,1,p);`
4. get the next array element element[i] with

   `val(t,element[i],code);`

Of course you have to code checks (Is the string s empty after some manipulation? If val gives an error, you have no valid number,...), array indexing etc.